# Disable a button based on a function result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, ecmascript-6, onclick

There is a button that must be disabled if a function return false. This function should be called every time something is changing in the input as the function checks if the introduced string is a valid email or not.

```
<button onClick={() => saveChanges()} disabled={() => checkChanges()}>click me</button>

const checkChanges = () => {
   // takes email value from state
   // checks if it's valid
   return valid; // it's either true or false
}
```

It doesn't work, is it something bad with disabled and how it is written?

Comment: You'll probably want `disabled={checkChanges()}` The browser uses the actual value, which in your code is a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `useState` variable and set result to it after calling `checkChanges()`

```
const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

const checkChanges = () => {
   // takes email value from state
   // checks if it's valid
   return setValid(result) // true or false after validating
}

 
return (<button onClick={() => saveChanges()} disabled={!valid}>click me</button>) {/* disable if not valid*/}
```